# Error during compilation of kernel

Tags: linux, compilation, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, arm

When i was compiling the kernel i got the following error.

```
wand-4.4.2_1/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi-ld: section .note.gnu.build-id loaded at [0000000000000000,0000000000000023] overlaps section .text loaded at [0000000000000000,0000000000203363]
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux] Error 1
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux] Error 2
```

I dont understand why this is coming.Can anybody tel me what this is?

Comment: I think you better give more info about you machine parameters and kernel configuration so other can help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028215/how-to-list-linker-allocated-code-objects-w-gcc

Comment: I am using the linux kernel for wandboard imx6 solo precessor.